# Old iOS firebase project with the firebase Google Sdk

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a ios app that used the old firebase with the sdk 2.5.1 from firebase. So I would like to update the firebase to the firebase google engine. It is necessary to update the database at the same time as the sdk? Bescause the AppStore review time is not so short. Is the new sdk down-compatible?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend that you read the [upgrade guide for iOS developers](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios). The most relevant snippet from there:

> You can upgrade your project to the new firebase.google.com console at any time. Your applications will continue to work. You can then update your code when you are ready to use some of the new Firebase features in your application.